# Heroku Assests Precompile Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Recently I upgraded ruby version of my Heroku application after which it stopped compiling assets.

Initially I was using ruby version 1.9.2 and my assets were getting compiled while deploying the application. Recently I upgraded ruby version to 1.9.3 by specifying in gem file and adding config variable "RUBY_VERSION" for my application.

Everything is working fine now it is also picking right ruby version but it is not running assets precompile command while deploying application.

I have following line in application.rb

> config.assets.enabled = true

Comment: I have the same issue; the only way I am able to get it to run on heroku is to set that to false (which I would love to avoid), but it does at least run at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow where the difference is - "...1.9.2 and my assets were getting compiled while deploying..." vs. "[with ruby 1.9.3] it is running assets precompile command while deploying". What's the difference between the two situations exactly? I'm missing what it is you're asking about and/or what you expected vs. the actual deployment/asset compilation behavior.

Comment: Basically after I upgraded to Ruby version 1.9.3, assets precompile command is not getting executing while deploying application on Heroku.

Comment: @Icicle `RUBY_VERSION` is depreciated and going away. Try unsetting it, and then adding `ruby "1.9.3"` in your `Gemfile` **before** the `source` line.

Comment: We followed above steps but still it is not executing assets precompile command while deploying application to Heroku.

Comment: Do you have any assets in your public directory? That might have snuck in somehow and caused Heroku to stop running the precompile step.

Comment: In Gemfile I added ruby "1.9.3" and I pushed the code to heroku.After pushing add this  heroku config:add BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/app/Gemfile  and restart heroku .

Comment: But again if I deploy the code I am getting this error::
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.1
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Your Ruby version is 1.9.2, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

Comment: Issue was solved.While deploying next time remove the bundler::
$ heroku config:remove BUNDLE_GEMFILE
$ git push heroku master 
and add the bundler file
$ heroku config:add BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/app/Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

A quick 'fix' for this would be precompiling the assets locally and then deploying the application.

I think its better, for a faster deployment.

First

```
rake assets:clean
```

then

```
RACK_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```